# MSVC program stops running instantly with no error

Tags: windows, qt, visual-c++

I've built an application with Qt 5.8 + MSVC15 on Windows 10. The application is running well on the host machine, but when I deploy the app on a fresh Windows 10 machine, at launch, I can see the application appearing in the Window Task Manager for a second and then disappearing.

The application crash gives no error dialog, and does not let anything in the system logs. I ran the dependency walker, but everything seems to be present in the application directory that I deploy.

Finally, I tried installing the VCRedist, but it does not change anything.

The application is working well on a Windows 7 machine though.

Thanks

Comment: If you were missing a DLL, I'd expect the OS to tell you that.  Have you tried adding some simple logging to your main/WinMain to see if the program begins to execute?  Have you tried making a trivial hello-world program on the development machine and seeing if you can get that to run on the target machine?

Comment: VCRedist would've been my first guess. What about graphics capabilities? Does your Qt application something require what the new Windows 10 computer is not able to provide? Btw. we use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out about DLL dependencies. Sometimes there are surprises as your app may resolve a DLL from anywhere but, of course, fails to do so on other (especially on fresh) systems.

Comment: Is it a Qt Quick (QML) or Widget application? If it is a Qt Quick application, you might miss some components giving you run-time errors. Make sure you used `windeployqt` with the proper `-qmldir` option.